# Unable to install tsd packages due to the following error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
d:\Angular2_SampleExamples\typings>tsd install angular2 es6-promise rx rx-lite --save
[ERR!] cwd  : d:\Angular2_SampleExamples\typings
[ERR!] os   : Windows_NT 6.1.7600
[ERR!] argv : "node" "C:\\Users\\WG97\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\tsd\\build\\cli.js" "install" "angular2" "es6-promise" "rx" "rx-lite" "--save"
[ERR!] node : v0.10.35
[ERR!] tsd  : 0.6.4
[ERR!] Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=6436:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c
:795:

[ERR!] CODE : ECONNRESET
[ERR!] tunneling socket could not be established, cause=6436:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:795:
```

This is most likely not a problem with tsd itself
and is related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
'proxy' config is set properly.  See: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#tsdrc

```
[ERR!] tsd.json could not be retrieved

[ERR!] .tsdrc could not be retrieved

[ERR!] Please include the following file with any support request:
    d:\Angular2_SampleExamples\typings\tsd-debug.log
```

Help required!

Comment: Have you tried googling `error 140770FC`? Besides that, the suggestion the error gave you it should be sufficient. You could also post the debug log you get as the error suggested as well.

Comment: if needed, consider running a local development NTLM proxy like http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ (there is a zip download somewhere), and point all tools to there

Comment: a simple way to overwrite corporate proxy server

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have security issue talking to github.
Create file:

.tsdrc

with following content:

```
{
     "strictSSL": false
}
```

and then try again.